# Agenda telefónica no muestra nombre correctamente

Tags: java, eclipse, archivo

Mi problema es que tengo el siguiente código Java y tengo que hacer lo que esta en la parte de arriba entre comentarios de la clase agenda, pues bien no me llega a funcionar correctamente. Por ejemplo, en la opción tres aun metiendo le un nombre que he dado de alta y que veo en el fichero binario no me lo muestra por pantalla. He investigado un poco y parece que el método `available()` me detecta que no hay bytes por leer cuando el fichero tiene contenido y ni siquiera a empezado a leer.

**Clase Agenda:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**en esta clase se utiliza la clase propia QuitarEspacios.java**/
/*
 * Realizar un programa que permita crear una agenda telefónica. 
 * De cada persona de la agenda se  almacenará: su nombre, teléfono, día y mes de cumpleaños, si es un contacto personal o de trabajo.
 * Los datos se almacenarán en un fichero.
 * Se dispondrá de un menú con las opciones
 * 1- Alta persona
 * 2- Baja persona
 * 3- Consulta Persona por nombre
 * 4- Mostrar personas que cumplen años hoy o mañana.
 * 5- Mostrar el número de personas almacenadas en el fichero.
 * 6- Crear un fichero que contenga todos los datos de las personas consideradas contactos personales.
 * 0- Fin
 * Todas las operaciones se realizarán directamente sobre el fichero sin utilizar estructuras de almacenamiento de memoria (arrays o similares).
 */
public class Agenda {

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    void menu(){
        File pathOri = new File("C:\\Users\\carlos\\Desktop\\prueba\\Datos_personas.dat");
        File pathCop = new File("C:\\Users\\carlos\\Desktop\\prueba\\Datos_personas_copia.dat");
        pathCop.deleteOnExit();
        DataOutputStream rutaDest = null;
        DataInputStream rutaOri = null;
        DataInputStream rutaOriCop = null;
        DataOutputStream rutaDestCop = null;

        try{
            pathCop.createNewFile();
            rutaDest = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathOri,true));//fichero Datos_personas, escribir
            rutaOri = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathOri));//fichero datos_personas, leer
            rutaOriCop = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathCop));//fichero datos_personas_copia, leer
            rutaDestCop = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathCop));//fichero datos_personas_copia, escribir
            QuitarEspacios qe = new QuitarEspacios();
            int opc, dia, mes;
            long telefono;
            String nombre, temp;
            char tipContact;
            Persona p = null;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean enc = false;
            Calendar fechaActual = new GregorianCalendar();

            do {
                System.out.println("1- Alta persona.");
                System.out.println("2- Baja persona.");
                System.out.println("3- Consulta Persona por nombre.");
                System.out.println("4- Mostrar personas que cumplen años hoy o mañana.");
                System.out.println("5- Mostrar el número de personas almacenadas en el fichero.");
                System.out.println("6- Crear un fichero que contenga todos los datos de las personas consideradas contactos personales.");
                System.out.println("0- Fin.");
                opc = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();

                switch(opc) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Dar nombre.(no se tendran en cuenta las mayusculas/minusculas al manejarlos).");
                    nombre = sc.nextLine();
                    nombre = qe.quitarEspacios(nombre);
                    System.out.println("Dar telefono.");
                    telefono = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Dar dia de nacimiento.");
                    dia = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Dar mes de nacimiento.");
                    mes = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Selecciones si es personal o de trabajo. Eliga 'Personal' o 'Trabajo'.");
                    temp = sc.nextLine();
                    tipContact = temp.charAt(0);
                    if(!buscar(rutaOri,nombre)) {
                        p = new Persona(nombre,telefono,dia,mes,tipContact);
                        p.escribir(rutaDest);
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Usuario ya registrado.");
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Dar nombre.");
                    nombre = sc.nextLine();
                    nombre = qe.quitarEspacios(nombre);
                    if(buscar(rutaOri,nombre)) {
                        p = new Persona();

                        while(rutaOri.available() > 0) {
                            p.leer(rutaOri);
                            if(!p.nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)) {
                                p.escribir(rutaDestCop);
                            }
                        }

                        rutaOri.close();
                        rutaDest.close();
                        pathOri.delete();
                        rutaDest = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathOri,true));
                        rutaOri = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathOri));

                        while(rutaOriCop.available() > 0) {
                            p.leer(rutaOriCop);
                            p.escribir(rutaDest);
                        }
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("No hay nadie con este nombre: "+nombre);
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Dar nombre.");
                    nombre = sc.nextLine();
                    nombre = qe.quitarEspacios(nombre);
                    if(buscar(rutaOri,nombre)) {
                        p = new Persona();
                        while(rutaOri.available() > 0 && !enc) {
                            p.leer(rutaOri);
                            if(p.nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)) {
                                System.out.println(p);
                                enc = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("No hay nadie con este nombre: "+nombre);
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    p = new Persona();
                    int temp1 = fechaActual.MONTH;
                    int temp2 = fechaActual.DAY_OF_MONTH - 1;
                    while(rutaOri.available() > 0) {
                        p.leer(rutaOri);
                        if(p.mes == temp1 && p.dia == temp2 || p.mes == temp1 && p.dia == temp2 + 1) {
                            System.out.println(p);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    int cont = 0;
                    p = new Persona();
                    while(rutaOri.available() > 0) {
                        p.leer(rutaOri);
                        cont++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Actualmente hay registradas "+cont+" personas.");
                    break;

                case 6:break;

                case 0:break;

                default: System.out.println("Opcion no valida.");
                }   
            }while(opc != 0);
            sc.close();
            rutaDest.close();
            rutaDestCop.close();
            rutaOri.close();
            rutaOriCop.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("No se ha podido encontrar el fichero donde se almacenan los datos.");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error los contactos solo pueden ser 'P' o 'T'");
        }
    }

    boolean buscar(DataInputStream rutaOri, String nombre) throws IOException {
        Persona p = new Persona();
        boolean encontrado = false;
        while(rutaOri.available() > 0 && !encontrado) {
            p.leer(rutaOri);
            if(p.nombre.equals(nombre)) {
                encontrado = true;
            }
        }
        return encontrado;
    }

    public static void main(String[]arg) {
        Agenda app = new Agenda();

        app.menu();
    }
}
```

**clase Persona:**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Persona {
    String nombre;
    long telefono;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    char tipContact;

    Persona(){}

    Persona(String nom, long tel, int day, int month, char typContact) throws Exception{
        if(typContact != 'P' && typContact != 'T') {
        throw new Exception();
        }
        nombre = nom;
        telefono = tel;
        dia = day;
        mes = month;
        tipContact = typContact;
    }

    void escribir(DataOutputStream rutaDest) throws IOException {
        rutaDest.writeUTF(nombre);
        rutaDest.writeLong(telefono);
        rutaDest.writeInt(dia);
        rutaDest.writeInt(mes);
        rutaDest.writeChar(tipContact);
        rutaDest.flush();
    }

    void leer(DataInputStream rutaOri) throws IOException {
        nombre = rutaOri.readUTF();
        telefono = rutaOri.readLong();
        dia = rutaOri.readInt();
        mes = rutaOri.readInt();
        tipContact = rutaOri.readChar();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Persona [nombre=" + nombre + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", dia=" + dia + ", mes=" + mes
                + ", tipContact=" + tipContact + "]";
    }
}
```

Lo siento por el código, no lo he podido presentar mejor.

Comment: Sería interesante poder ver el resultado de la ventana del output del Netbeans o el IDE que estes usando. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo arregle amigos era porque al no cerrar el fichero y volver lo abrir el ountero se quedaba al final del fichero. Luego, cuando me iba a un while en el que la condicion era que quedasen bytes por leer no me entraba por el haber se quedado al final. Al cerrar y abrirlo de nuevo el pumtero vuelve al principio, solucion cerrar lo cada vez que he terminado la lectura del fichero para que la proxima vez que quiera leer el puntero este al principio.